# executing javascript with a DOM BASED XSS

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss

i'am facing a really hard challenge for me ,i need to be able to inject javascript code into the name of a window to make an alert(1) for example :

here is the image of the dom :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu7Vi.png

when trying to put manually alert(1) into the value case i just have an alert ,so i tried to execute a script to make the same thing but i didn't succed .

here is my script :

```
 <script>
window.open("mypage.html", "alert(1);", "", false);
</script>
```

Comment: How is that window name processed that you’re assuming it’s vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: I think the task is to use XSS to change window name in presented script, not to make XSS attack on window name param of window.open function...